# Plymouth scrolling text

Tags: fedora, boot

Is it possible to have it default to scrolling text on boot/shutdown  versus the Fedora icon? I know I can get it by hitting various keys, but can I get it to default to text and those messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `plymouth` to show the messages as text like so:

```
$ plymouth-set-default-theme text
$ /usr/libexec/plymouth/plymouth-update-initrd
```

#### References

- [RHEL6 - disable the tiered-progress bar during boot](https://superuser.com/questions/257888/rhel6-disable-the-tiered-progress-bar-during-boot)
- [How do I change my boot theme?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10270/how-do-i-change-my-boot-theme/)